# "Unsatisfiable requirements detected for the package" in Julia

Tags: package, julia

I am getting an error while adding packages to the julia:

## Error

DataFrame

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add DataFrames
   Updating registry at `C:\Users\.julia\registries\JuliaComputingRegistry`
  Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package DataFramesMeta [1313f7d8]:
 DataFramesMeta [1313f7d8] log:
 ├─DataFramesMeta [1313f7d8] has no known versions!
 └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement — no versions left
```

CUDA

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add CUDA
  Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package CUDA [052768ef]:
 CUDA [052768ef] log:
 ├─CUDA [052768ef] has no known versions!
 └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement — no versions left
```

This happens every time I try to add any package to julia. I have tried reinstalling the julia but the issue still persist.

Please suggest a solution to this issue. I have also posted this issue on [julia-discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-unsatisfiable-requirements-detected-for-package/54901).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the comment on discourse.

Comment: Feel free to cross post the answer here if you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

The issue is related to cloning of registry during update. Apparently, it is some kind of a bug.
To resolve this issue, you may delete the `registry/General` folder and then restart Julia. This will make Julia to rebuild all the packages and then everything should run smoothly.

To delete the folder, one may either go to console and perform following operations:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> registry rm General
  Removing registry `General` from ~/.julia/registries/General
```

`or`

Look for the folder `.julia/registries/General` (tested in windows) and delete it manually. (Path will look something like this: `C:\Users\User\.julia\registries\General`

Thanks!!