# ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Mux [a975b10e]:

Tags: error-handling, julia

I am trying to install the `PlotlyJS` package, but I get the following error:

```
julia> Pkg.add("PlotlyJS")
   Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Mux [a975b10e]:
 Mux [a975b10e] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.4.0-1.0.1 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with HTTP [cd3eb016] to versions: 1.0.0-1.0.1 or uninstalled
 │ └─HTTP [cd3eb016] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.6.10-1.6.2 or uninstalled
 │   ├─restricted to versions 1 by Genie [c43c736e], leaving only versions 1.0.0-1.6.2
 │   │ └─Genie [c43c736e] log:
 │   │   ├─possible versions are: 5.13.0 or uninstalled
 │   │   └─Genie [c43c736e] is fixed to version 5.13.0
 │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with LoggingExtras [e6f89c97] to versions: [0.6.10-0.9.17, 1.5.4-1.6.2] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 1.5.4-1.6.2
 │     └─LoggingExtras [e6f89c97] log:
 │       ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-1.0.0 or uninstalled
 │       └─restricted to versions 1 by Genie [c43c736e], leaving only versions 1.0.0
 │         └─Genie [c43c736e] log: see above
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Blink [ad839575] to versions: 0.7.0-0.7.6 — no versions left
   └─Blink [ad839575] log:
     ├─possible versions are: 0.8.0-0.12.5 or uninstalled
     └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Reexport [189a3867] to versions: 0.12.5 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.12.5
       └─Reexport [189a3867] log:
         ├─possible versions are: 0.2.0-1.2.2 or uninstalled
         └─restricted to versions 1 by Genie [c43c736e], leaving only versions 1.0.0-1.2.2
           └─Genie [c43c736e] log: see above
Stacktrace:
  [1] propagate_constraints!(graph::Pkg.Resolve.Graph, sources::Set{Int64}; log_events::Bool)
    @ Pkg.Resolve /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:1072
  [2] propagate_constraints! (repeats 2 times)
    @ /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:1008 [inlined]
  [3] simplify_graph!(graph::Pkg.Resolve.Graph, sources::Set{Int64}; clean_graph::Bool)
    @ Pkg.Resolve /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:1533
  [4] simplify_graph! (repeats 2 times)
    @ /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:1532 [inlined]
  [5] resolve_versions!(env::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, registries::Vector{Pkg.Registry.RegistryInstance}, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, julia_version::VersionNumber)
    @ Pkg.Operations /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:352
  [6] targeted_resolve(env::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, registries::Vector{Pkg.Registry.RegistryInstance}, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, julia_version::VersionNumber)
    @ Pkg.Operations /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1254
  [7] tiered_resolve(env::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, registries::Vector{Pkg.Registry.RegistryInstance}, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, julia_version::VersionNumber)
    @ Pkg.Operations /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1239
  [8] _resolve(io::Base.TTY, env::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, registries::Vector{Pkg.Registry.RegistryInstance}, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, julia_version::VersionNumber)
    @ Pkg.Operations /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1260
  [9] add(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, new_git::Set{Base.UUID}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform)
    @ Pkg.Operations /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1276
 [10] add(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Base.TTY, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:io,), Tuple{Base.TTY}}})
    @ Pkg.API /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:275
 [11] add(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; io::Base.TTY, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Pkg.API /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:156
 [12] add(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec})
    @ Pkg.API /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:145
 [13] #add#27
    @ /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:144 [inlined]
 [14] add
    @ /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:144 [inlined]
 [15] #add#26
    @ /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:143 [inlined]
 [16] add(pkg::String)
    @ Pkg.API /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/API.jl:143
 [17] top-level scope
    @ REPL[18]:1
```

I am using Julia version 1.8.3:

```
julia> VERSION
v"1.8.3"
```

I tried using `registry rm General` like in this question ["Unsatisfiable requirements detected for the package" in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114900/unsatisfiable-requirements-detected-for-the-package-in-julia), but that doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you linked is unfortunately not very helpful for the majority of "unsatisfiable requirements detected" errors - as you can see there, the error is actually that no version of a package are being found, even thought the package has a number of releases. This is indeed indicative of a corrupt local package registry.

Your case however is different: multiple different versions for all packages in the error message are being found, so there clearly isn't an issue with the registry.

Your question is basically a duplicate of the question I answered here:

[Julia "Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package" error when installing multiple packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73054419/julia-unsatisfiable-requirements-detected-for-package-error-when-installing-mu?rq=1)

which is the more common scenario for "unsatisfiable requirements" issues: you actually have unsatisfiable requirements in the sense that you are trying to install a set of packages into an environment which require incompatible versions of shared dependencies.

However, your issue seems to have a slight twist compared to the linked question above, check out what happens when I do what I did in the other answer and install the packages you're trying to install here (`PlotlyJS` and `Genie`) into a new environment:

```
(@v1.8) pkg> activate --temp
  Activating new project at `/tmp/jl_4HTNUi`

(jl_ox50Zr) pkg> add PlotlyJS Genie
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
(...)
    Updating `/tmp/jl_ox50Zr/Project.toml`
⌃ [c43c736e] + Genie v5.2.2
  [f0f68f2c] + PlotlyJS v0.18.10
```

No error, the operation resolved successfully and I now have Genie installed alongside PlotlyJS. Based on the error message above and my answer in the linked question above, I would have expected this to error so what's going on?

The clue is in two things:

1. Note the little caret before the `Genie` entry in the `Project.toml` of the temporary environment above: `⌃ [c43c736e] + Genie v5.2.2` - this tells us that the `Genie` version installed is not the latest available version (a feature introduced in Julia 1.8); and
2. Note this additional bit of info in your error message:

```
 │   │ └─Genie [c43c736e] log:
 │   │   ├─possible versions are: 5.13.0 or uninstalled
 │   │   └─Genie [c43c736e] is fixed to version 5.13.0
```

So the issue you're facing is not installing `PlotlyJS` and `Genie` per se, but rather adding `PlotlyJS` to an environment in which you *specifically require* `Genie` at version 0.5.13`. Let's confirm that that's the issue in a new temp environment:

```
(@v1.8) pkg> activate --temp
  Activating new project at `/tmp/jl_4HTNUi`

(jl_4HTNUi) pkg> add PlotlyJS Genie@5.13
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Mux [a975b10e]:
 Mux [a975b10e] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.4.0-1.0.1 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with HTTP [cd3eb016] to versions: 1.0.0-1.0.1 or uninstalled
 │ └─HTTP [cd3eb016] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.6.10-1.6.2 or uninstalled
 │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Genie [c43c736e] to versions: 1.0.0-1.6.2
 │     └─Genie [c43c736e] log:
 │       ├─possible versions are: 0.9.4-5.13.0 or uninstalled
 │       └─restricted to versions 5.13 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 5.13.0
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Blink [ad839575] to versions: 0.4.0-0.7.6 — no versions left
   └─Blink [ad839575] log:
     ├─possible versions are: 0.8.0-0.12.5 or uninstalled
```

Which is a version of the error you're seeing. So indeed you are trying to do something that doesn't work: Genie 0.5.13 isn't compatible with PlotlyJS based on their respective dependencies, so you'll either have to work with an older Genie version, or a different plotting package, or change the compatibility bounds for PlotlyJS's dependencies to make things work (this is non-trivial, if you do so and things work you should consider making a PR upstream to allow everyone to access the updated version).